# Error:Kotlin: Unsupported plugin option: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true "reloaded"

Tags: android, kotlin

The following problem drives me crazy.

Whenever I start the Kotlin-REPL from within Android-Studio, I get the following message:

```
You’re running the REPL with outdated classes: Build module 'app' and restart

 Welcome to Kotlin version 1.2.71 (JRE 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)  Type :help for help, :quit for quit
```

Rebuilding module 'app' by clicking on the link, results into:

```
There were compilation errors in module app

and Error: Kotlin: Unsupported plugin option: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true
```

I just made a clean install of Android-Studio 3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

> Android Studio 3.2   Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on
>   September 17, 2018   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64   JVM:
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o   Linux 4.15.0-36-generic

I also upgraded to the latest Kotlin Plugin.

> Current Kotlin plugin version: 1.2.71-release-Studio3.2-1

I tried out all tips, that where posted on similar occurrences of that problem, but nothing helped.

My module build.gradle contains:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gisc0.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner   
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `.gradle` files?

Comment: Above I added the contents of the module-level build.gradle. It happens at a pure generated "New project". No modifications done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Kotlin: Unsupported plugin option: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789802/errorkotlin-unsupported-plugin-option-org-jetbrains-kotlin-androidenabled-tr)